# Установка программы с github

Tags: git, debian, github

Как я понимаю Github создан с целью (поправьте если не прав) разработки (для разработчиков) и для клиентов (с целью слежения последней версии программы)
То есть если выходит последняя версия программы, я запускаю нужную команду, идет сверка и если есть изменения в исходниках - гит закачивает последнюю версию исходников. Чтобы я потом мог успешно скомпилировать под свой процессор.

https://github.com/eternity-group/eternity

На примере этого линка, как скачать исходники самым простым способом? (Debian)
И какой командой можно проверить есть ли обновления?

Git вроде как установлен. Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1

Comment: Ответ ни о чем. Мне нужен пример.

Comment: Самый простой способ для Вас, полагаю - большая зелёная кнопка "Clone or download", и в выпадающем меню нажать "Download ZIP". 
А так - ниже ответ с краткой справкой по работе с git, подробнее можно посмотреть в man git. А выше комментарий со ссылкой на самый лучший (ИМХО) мануал по гиту.

Comment: @spopovru, у него Debian.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержанию. Установить — совсем не то же самое, что получить исходники для компиляции.

Comment: Ваш изначальный посыл про клиентов (кого вы имеете в виду здесь?) неверен.

Comment: 1. Установить С github или ИЗ если хотите. Речь не шла об установке самого git
2. Клиент - терминология из Клиент-Сервер. Сервер (разработчик) - главный. Клиент (пользователь если хотите).

Ребята спасибо проблема решена чуть ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить исходники (загрузятся в папку `eternity`):

```
git clone https://github.com/eternity-group/eternity.git
```

Получить исходники в папку `custom`:

```
git clone https://github.com/eternity-group/eternity.git custom
```

Проверить обновления (при условии, что скачали в папку `eternity`):

```
cd eternity
git remote -v update
```

Получить обновления:

```
git pull
```

Comment: Вот за это огромное спасибо!